# Access extrenal db service from App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mongodb, mongohq

Specifically I'm trying to access MonogoHQ, using the the Monogo Java Driver, 
It's work locally but on the server I'm getting

There is some limitation,
 So the MongoDb Java Driver doesn't work when I try to create connection using:
`MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "mydb.mongohq.com", 10014 );`

Comment: If you can settle with MongoDB-like API you may want to try: https://github.com/mungo-appengine/mungo

Answer (score 5):

Google Appengine doesn't allow socket connections unless you've enabled billing for your app. From the Google docs:

> Note: **Sockets are only available for paid apps**, and traffic from sockets is billed as outgoing bandwidth. Sockets are also limited by daily and per minute (burst) quotas.

From [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/).